# Can Linux cache domain user credentials?

Tags: linux, user-management

I want to centrally manage users on my small network at home, preferably in a mixed Windows/Linux environment. (I'm transitioning to Linux to avoid Windows 10.)

**Is it possible to cache users on a linux computer the way Windows caches its AD users?** Here's an example of what I want to do: I want to log in to bgstack@mydomain whether or not I'm attached to my home network, on a linux system. When I take my laptop to my friend's house, I still want to use bgstack@mydomain.

If a solution exists, does it matter which directory server I use? I have not yet implemented any linux identity management solution yet but was leaning towards [FreeIPA](http://www.freeipa.org/page/Main_Page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly how I use sssd. On my laptop, I run as the user from our corporate LDAP:

```
jhrozek@hendrix ~ » whoami
jhrozek
```

Yet I don't have that user in /etc/passwd at all:

```
jhrozek@hendrix ~ » grep jhrozek /etc/passwd
jhrozek@hendrix ~ » echo $?
1
```

The setup really depends on what kind of server you use, but SSSD supports MSAD, FreeIPA, LDAP and Kerberos.

Comment: So sssd already has the caching baked in? That would be fantastic, as I know how to set up sssd from work already.

Comment: Yes, user identity information is cached by default, credential caching must be explicitly enabled by setting cache_credentials=true. Please note that the credentials are cached when you log in, so at least the first login must be done when the client is connected to the network.

Answer (score 0):

Centrify is a commercial product that integrates linux with AD and it can cache credentials and homedirs. [Centrify.com](https://www.centrify.com/)

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. Provide at least a link, as well as some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: Do you know if Centrify can be used with a linux directory server, and not just AD?